# 同一サイトの特定のファイルだけがローカルで取得できてサーバで取得できない時の対処法

Tags: ruby

[こちらのサイト](http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/search.php?target=pcsl)のcsvを毎日さくらのVPSから自動で保存しています。

保存には以下の様なスクリプトを使っていて、今までは問題なくまた現在も4/24、4/17以外の最近のデータは取得できます。またローカルからアクセスした場合は全て問題なくダウンロードできます。

```
  def get_csv(date_string)
    stream = open("http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=#{date_string}", "r:shift_jis")
    return if stream.content_type != "text/x-csv"
    csv_text = stream.read.encode("utf-8", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
  end

  get_csv("2015-04-17")
```

もし、相手先のサーバーがVPSからのアクセスをはじくようになったのであれば取得は諦めて別の方法を探そうと思うのですが、他の日付を取得できることからアクセス制限ではないと思うんです。

どうやらサーバー上から取得した時は`stream.content_type`が`text/html`になってしまっているのが原因のようです。

何故このような事が起こるかわからないのですが、調査方法また解決策はどのようなものがありますか？

Comment: VPSからは、現在同じ方法でリトライしても取得できないのでしょうか？

Comment: `text/html` の時は200以外のレスポンスコードが返ってきていませんか？レスポンスコードとContentを調べましょう。

Comment: @junichi-ito さんから出して頂いている実行結果の text/html 部分は 404 ですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

即席のスクリプトを作ってローカルで4/1-4/30のデータ(content-type)を取得してみました。

```
require 'open-uri'

def get_csv(date_string)
  url = "http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=#{date_string}"
  puts url
  stream = open(url, "r:shift_jis")
  stream.content_type
  # return if stream.content_type != "text/x-csv"
  # csv_text = stream.read.encode("utf-8", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
end

(1..30).each do |i|
  puts get_csv("2015-04-#{i.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}")
  sleep 0.5
end
```

実行結果（text/x-csvとtext/htmlが混在している）

```
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-01
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-02
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-03
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-04
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-05
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-06
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-07
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-08
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-09
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-10
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-11
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-12
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-13
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-14
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-15
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-16
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-17
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-18
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-19
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-20
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-21
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-22
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-23
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-24
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-25
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-26
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-27
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-28
text/x-csv
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-29
text/html
http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-30
text/x-csv
```

で、この実行結果と http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/search.php?target=pcsl を開いてみて思ったのですが、失敗しているのは単純に「データが存在しない日付がある」というだけではありませんか？

「ローカルからアクセスした場合は全て問題なくダウンロードできる」というのも、実はたまたまデータが存在している日付のみにアクセスしたから、ではないですか？

実際、ブラウザで http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-18 にアクセスしてみると「指定された日付の品貸料率一覧表はありません。」という文言が表示されます。
一方、 http://www.jsf.co.jp/de/stock/dlcsv.php?target=pcsl&date=2015-04-17 であればCSVファイルがダウンロードされます。

もう一度対象の日付と実行結果の関係を見直してみてください。

### P.S.

質問で挙げられているコードでは、引数の`date_string`が使われていません。`@date`がnilだったりするとうまく動かないと思うので、実際に使っているコードにも問題が無いか確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。データのない日付の取得を行おうとして閉まっていたのが原因でした。